# Load file from Gradle parent directory into Java test

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

I have a multi-module Gradle `5.4.1` project. The folder structure looks like:

```
root
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    - conf-folder/config.conf
    - module-a/ (a Java submodule)
    - module-b/ (a Java submodule)
```

In `module-a` I have a JUnit test that needs to read `conf-folder/config.conf`. I've tried `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf-folder/config.conf");` which (unsurprisingly) doesn't work as `conf-folder` isn't within `module-a`, so how do I access this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may edit the `build.gradle` file for module-a

```
println("rootDir=$rootDir")
sourceSets.test.resources.srcDir file("$rootDir/conf-folder")
```

and retrieve the resource as

```
System.out.printf("res=%s%n", this.getClass().getResource("/config.conf"));
```

Comment: Uhm, why do you need to add the `test` bloc? I would think the given script is enough (the folder is added to the test configuration only, and is not added to the main config)

Comment: it's working outside of the test block, yesterday it wouldn't even compile outside of it. Thanks agian.